# Stubbing virtual attributes of Mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongoose, sinon

Is there a way to stub a virtual attribute of a Mongoose Model?

Assume `Problem` is a model class, and `difficulty` is a virtual attribute. `delete Problem.prototype.difficulty` returns false, and the attribute is still there, so I can't replace it with any value I want.

I also tried

```
var p = new Problem();
delete p.difficulty;
p.difficulty = Problem.INT_EASY;
```

It didn't work.

Assigning undefined to `Problem.prototype.difficulty` or using `sinon.stub(Problem.prototype, 'difficulty').returns(Problem.INT_EASY);`
 would throw an exception "TypeError: Cannot read property 'scope' of undefined", while doing

```
  var p = new Problem();
  sinon.stub(p, 'difficulty').returns(Problem.INT_EASY);
```

would throw an error "TypeError: Attempted to wrap string property difficulty as function".

I am running out of ideas. Help me out! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mongoose [internally uses](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/f1baebafdbdf4dd9207b250585a3ae14d1fb4bdc/lib/document.js#L1197) `Object.defineProperty` for all properties. Since they are defined as non-configurable, you can't [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) them, and you can't [re-configure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Modifying_a_property) them, either.

What you can do, though, is overwriting the model’s `get` and `set` methods, which are used to get and set any property:

```
var p = new Problem();
p.get = function (path, type) {
  if (path === 'difficulty') {
    return Problem.INT_EASY;
  }
  return Problem.prototype.get.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Or, a complete example using sinon.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var sinon = require('sinon');

var problemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({});
problemSchema.virtual('difficulty').get(function () {
  return Problem.INT_HARD;
});

var Problem = mongoose.model('Problem', problemSchema);
Problem.INT_EASY = 1;
Problem.INT_HARD = 2;

var p = new Problem();
console.log(p.difficulty);
sinon.stub(p, 'get').withArgs('difficulty').returns(Problem.INT_EASY);
console.log(p.difficulty);
```

Comment: Overriding `get` works, but stubbing with sinon would throw a TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined. So I used the first solution. Thanks!

Comment: I posted a complete example with sinon that works for me (node@0.10.18, mongoose@3.6.19, sinon@1.7.3).

Comment: I added a `regionId` to the problemSchema of your example, now regionId can't be assigned after stubbing with sinon. That was why I got the error when I try to assert that `['Mount Silversword', 'Ainsley Field'].should.include(p.regionId);`

Comment: I see now that I misunderstood how stubs work exactly. I thought they would transparently call the original function if nothing else is specified, but that’s not the case. Seems like you are stuck with the first solution.

Comment: Thanks, I am fine with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

As of the end of 2017 and the current Sinon version, stubbing only some of the arguments (e.g. only virtuals on mongoose models) can be achieved in the following manner

```
  const ingr = new Model.ingredientModel({
    productId: new ObjectID(),
  });

  // memorizing the original function + binding to the context
  const getOrigin = ingr.get.bind(ingr);

  const getStub = S.stub(ingr, 'get').callsFake(key => {

    // stubbing ingr.$product virtual
    if (key === '$product') {
      return { nutrition: productNutrition };
    }

    // stubbing ingr.qty
    else if (key === 'qty') {
      return { numericAmount: 0.5 };
    }

    // otherwise return the original 
    else {
      return getOrigin(key);
    }

  });
```

The solution is inspired by a bunch of different advises, including one by @Adrian Heine