# Can't override property of an JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got a method that is formatting the `date` property of a `message`. A user has an array of `messages`.

```
user.messages[i].date = formatDate(user.messages[i].date);

// logs the correctly formatted date
console.log(formatDate(user.messages[i].date));

// logs the unformatted date 
console.log(user.messages[i].date);
```

However, when I do it like the following code snippet it works.

```
        user.messages[i] = {
            name: user.messages[i].name,
            body: user.messages[i].body,
            _id: user.messages[i]._id,
            date: formatDate(user.messages[i].date)
        };
```

Comment: if it works so what's the question? ;)

Comment: your first block modifies an object, your second block _replaces_ the entire object with a new one.

Comment: There's probably something you aren't showing here. Try `var msg = user.messages[i]; msg.date = formatDate(msg.date); console.log(msg.date);` It is not possible that the assignment doesn't work, unless you defined the `data` property as being non-confugurable using `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: There don't seem to be any problems with that particular code. Could you provide a reproducible scenario of your problem?

Comment: The user object is an object I retrieve from mongodb using a mongoose model. Maybe it is non-configurable then, I'll look this up.

Comment: @user1772306 Can you include the `Schema` here? If the property has a `type` of `Date`, you won't be able to specify how it's formatted in storage.

Comment: It is indeed Date. But I'm somehow refused to change it to String, since I only want to format the Date before sending it to the view.

Comment: Welcome to ES5 getters and setters where a variable is not what it seems. Used to be we only had to deal with `innerHTML` behaving this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the comment from @plalx, I found a solution in this thread:

[Stubbing virtual attributes of Mongoose model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412606/stubbing-virtual-attributes-of-mongoose-model)

Comment: I may do this after 2 days. (earlier it isn't possible)

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess but you could add formatteddate:"" into your user model (or similar) and then try:

```
user.messages[i].formatteddate = formatDate(user.messages[i].date);
```

Therefore you are not re-configuring it.